# Laravel query search behaving strangely

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm having some troubles with a query search to post to a table frontend.
I admit I'm not exactly a huge expert on laravel, been working with it for only 3 months or so.

Here's the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
$orders = Order::whereNot('status', 'pending')->has('items')->orderBy('updated_at', "desc");
  $ordersUsers = $orders;
  $ordersCourses = $orders;
  $ordersRegattas = $orders;
        
  if($request->input('s')){
      $ordersUsers = $ordersUsers->whereHas('user',function($query) use ($request){
          $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->input('s').'%')
          ->orWhere('last_name','LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%')->orWhere(
              DB::raw("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)"), 'LIKE', '%' 
              .$request->input('s') . '%');
      });

      $ordersCourses = $ordersCourses->whereHas('items', function($query2) use ($request) {
          $query2->where('type', 'App\Models\Course')->whereHas('courseSubscription',
          function($query2) use ($request){               
              $query2->whereState(CourseSubscription::SUBSCRIPTION_COMPLETED)
              ->whereHas('attendees', function($query2) use ($request) {
                  $query2->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') .'%')
                  ->orWhere('surname','LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%')->orWhere(
                       DB::raw("concat(name, ' ', surname)"), 'LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') .  
                       '%');
               });
           });
       });
       $ordersRegattas = $ordersRegattas->whereHas('items', function($query3) use ($request) {
           $query3->whereType('App\Models\Regatta')->whereHas('regattaSubscription',  
           function($query3) use ($request){
               $query3->whereHas('regattaattendees', function($query3) use ($request) {
                    $query3->where(function($query3) use ($request) {
                        $query3->where('is_owner', 1)->where('owner_partecipate',   
                        1)->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') .   
                        '%')->orWhere('surname','LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . 
                        '%')->orWhere(
                                DB::raw("concat(name, ' ', surname)"), 'LIKE', '%' 
                        .$request->input('s') . '%');
                    })->orWhere(function($query3) use ($request) {
                        $query3->where('is_owner', 0)->where('owner_partecipate', 0)
                        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%')
                        ->orWhere('surname','LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%')->orWhere(
                            DB::raw("concat(name, ' ', surname)"), 'LIKE', '%'  
                            .$request->input('s') . '%');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        $orders = $ordersRegattas;
    }
    $orders = $orders->paginate(20);
    return view('society.orders.index', compact('orders'));
```

Structures of the models involved:

-Orders have multiple OrderItems (items), hasMany relation and a user, hasOne relation

-OrderItems have types, regatta/course in this case, and a relative subscription type (regattaSubscription and courseSubscription)

-these subs have attendees with name/surname, and in the case of regatta attendees there's another layer of conditions, "is_owner" and "owner_partecipates" which need to be both 0 or 1 to be considerered.

Basically I should retrieve orders whose user name/surname is equal to the input, or whose subscriptions attendees have that name/surname combo

In my old code I tied all three queries in one massive "orWhere" query, and it worked, then suddenly it stopped, as in it started to return orders which violated the first condition set, whereNot('status', 'pending')->has('items')

Thinking I must've remembered wrong and that I screwed up the orWhere orders I decided to just separate them in three queries and merge the result in the table in the frontend.

And that's where my problem came out: if I comment out 2 of the 3 queries, the last remaining works, but if all three are active, either the $order list is empty or it returns the results of the first query, even if not called (in this example, this code returned the orders of $ordersUsers)

I tried giving each a unique $query variable in case they were conflicting in some way, but to no avail.

I've tried looking up some documentation, but couldnt find anything of the sort, did I miss something or this is not expected behaviour?

Old code for reference:

```
    $orders = Order::whereNot('status', 'pending')->has('items')->orderBy('updated_at', "desc");
    
    if($request->input('s')){
        $orders = $orders->whereHas('user',function($query) use ($request){
            return $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%')->orWhere('last_name','LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%')->orWhere(
                DB::raw("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)"), 'LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%'
            );;
        })->orWhereHas('items', function($query) use ($request) {
            return $query->whereType('App\Models\Course')->whereHas('courseSubscription', function($query) use ($request){
                return $query->whereState(CourseSubscription::SUBSCRIPTION_COMPLETED)->whereHas('attendees', function($query) use ($request) {
                    return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%')->orWhere('surname','LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%')->orWhere(
                        DB::raw("concat(name, ' ', surname)"), 'LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%'
                    );
                });
            });
        })->orWhereHas('items', function($query) use ($request) {
            return $query->whereType('App\Models\Regatta')->whereHas('regattaSubscription', function($query) use ($request){
                return $query->whereState(RegattaSubscription::SUBSCRIPTION_COMPLETED)->whereHas('regattaattendees', function($query) use ($request) {
                    return $query->where(function($query) use ($request) {
                        return $query->where('is_owner', 1)->where('owner_partecipate', 1)->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%')->orWhere('surname','LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%')->orWhere(
                            DB::raw("concat(name, ' ', surname)"), 'LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%'
                        );
                    })->orWhere(function($query) use ($request) {
                        return $query->where('is_owner', 0)->where('owner_partecipate', 0)->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%')->orWhere('surname','LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%')->orWhere(
                            DB::raw("concat(name, ' ', surname)"), 'LIKE', '%' .$request->input('s') . '%'
                        );
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
    $orders = $orders->paginate(20)->withQueryString();
    return view('society.orders.index', compact('orders'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$orders,$ordersUsers,$ordersCourses,$ordersRegattas all are accessing the same memory location of the server. You should do

```php
$ordersUsers = clone $orders;
$ordersCourses = clone $orders;
$ordersRegattas = clone $orders;
```

also, put order by and common query at last,

my submission is

```
$orders = Order::query();
  $ordersUsers = clone $orders;
  $ordersCourses = clone $orders;
  $ordersRegattas = clone $orders;
  if($request->input('s')){
   .................
   .................
   .................

  }

  $orders->whereNot('status', 'pending')->has('items')->orderBy('updated_at', "desc")->$paginate(20);
```

Comment: Ah-ha! I knew I was missing something! Thank you